# Make button faded so you can't click on it

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing some Swing and I have a little design issue. I want to increase some HCI and make my buttons unclickable. Or more precisely, I want them to be visible, but not clickable.

```
JButton button = new JButton();
frame.add(button);
```

I just want a quick and fast way to, no advanced things. the setVisible() method did not to the job, and I understand why, since it does a whole other thing.

Comment: Have you tried `.setEnabled(False)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this on your button when you want to fade it:

```
button.setEnabled(false);

// to show it again:
button.setEnabled(true);
```